# R , on shift indicator, comes on when key is inserted into ignition. Engine won’t turn over

Tags: tacoma

2017 Toyota Tacoma. About once every 3-5 months, when I insert key in ignition “R” on shift indicator comes on. When key is turned nothing happens. Like no current is going to starter. Shifter is in park. Toyota says they have never heard of this problem and have no solution. After about 2-3 hours problem goes away.

Comment: Does the shifter need adjustment? Has it been checked? is it just "slipping" from P to R?

Comment: Shifter isn't slipping. Stays in P. Apparently the vehicles computer thinks it's in R even though it isn't. As soon as key in inserted in ignition (shifter in P) the back-up camera comes on as if you wanted to back up. Moving the shifter to R or any other position doesn't help.

Comment: It sound like the shifter interlock switch is loose.

Comment: I suggested neutral safety switch to toy dealer and it was dismissed with a shake of the head. Toyota has no suggestions - no idea.